# How can I make my buttons all the same size/ fill the table part no matter how much text is in them

Tags: html, css, button, html-table

I try to make buttons in a table that should all be the full size of their table part. but if I adjust my browser width they should also adjust to fit the text. the problem is, that some buttons grow larger than others due to the text being longer. I want that the other buttons adjust their size to the biggest one of them. how can I fix this?

```css
.essenskarte {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.essenskarte button {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px double #cccccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="essenskarte">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="weinknorze">Pfälzer Weinknorze</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="kaesewuerfel">Käsewürfel</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="feta">Gegrillter Feta</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="winzerkaes">Winzerkäs</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="spundekaes">Spundekäs</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="saumagen">Saumagen-Carpaccio</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="lachs">Geräucherter Lachs</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="curry">Curry-Reispfanne</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="schnitzel">Mailänder Schnitzel</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="jaegerschnitzel">Jägerschnitzel</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="kroketten" style="background-color: rgb(255, 226, 80)">Kroketten</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="fleischkloesse">Fleischklöße</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="submit" name="schweinebaeckchen">Schweinebäckchen</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
.essenskarte {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.essenskarte button {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px double #cccccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

I tried to auto adjust the buttons to the table size to make them always the full size, which works in the standard 16:9 1080p ratio but not in any other resolution.

Comment: Perhaps consider different layout elements than `<table` which can be hard to style consistently.  Why are these `type="submit"` are they in a form?

Comment: If you need to keep it as a table (ie if your data in the real-life case is tabular) then consider styling the tds rather than their buttons.

Comment: yes, it is all inside a form

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid the buttons growing larger than others due to the text being longer when adjusting the browser window size by adding the min-width property to the essenskarte class, here's an example of the mind-width for my browser, you may change the number accordingly, you can also add the max-width property for bigger screens.

```
 .essenskarte {
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      min-width:821px}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: hi, sadly this doesnt help because it must be accessible for mobile use as well

Comment: You want to make sure that your code blocks have appropriate syntax highlighting, or any at all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a table use a set of divs formatted as a grid. You may have to do some adjustment to make the visual fit but when too narrow the buttons should wrap - like on a mobile device or narrow screen/browser.

```css
body,
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.parent-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.row-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 9em);
  grid-template-rows: 3em;
  grid-gap: 0;
}

.row-container>* {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.essenskarte button {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 4px double #cccccc;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 3%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="essenskarte parent-container">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="weinknorze">Pfälzer Weinknorze</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="kaesewuerfel">Käsewürfel</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="feta">Gegrillter Feta</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="winzerkaes">Winzerkäs</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="spundekaes">Spundekäs</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="saumagen">Saumagen-Carpaccio</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="lachs">Geräucherter Lachs</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="curry">Curry-Reispfanne</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="schnitzel">Mailänder Schnitzel</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="jaegerschnitzel">Jägerschnitzel</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="kroketten" style="background-color: rgb(255, 226, 80)">Kroketten</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="fleischkloesse">Fleischklöße</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="schweinebaeckchen">Schweinebäckchen</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```